# Scripting keyboard input with Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm hoping to write a script that can control GNU Screen for example split the screen with 'Ctrl + S'. My ultimate objective is to run 4 different applications with a single script. Is this possible within Ruby?

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt there is any key capture library out there. You can try to write it in C and wrap up

Comment: You can do this without too much difficulty in JRuby, since Java can do this. Alternatively, I've done this sort of thing with [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/), a very impressive Jython framework for doing this sort of thing, complete with screenshot analysis for determining where to click. Posting as a comment because I'm too tired to do the research to make a proper answer with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found any pre-made Ruby solution, but there are various pages about doing it with shell commands. For example, [Scripting screen for fun and profit](http://www.jerri.de/blog/archives/2006/05/02/scripting_screen_for_fun_and_profit/).

Other Stack Exchange questions: [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/155851/run-gnu-screen-from-script) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899609/gnu-screen-run-script-that-sends-commands-to-the-screen-session-it-is-being-run) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156290/how-do-you-script-gnu-screen-from-within-a-screen-session-to-open-new-windows-an).

Comment: The blog link has a working technique! Thank you!

`screen -X split`